# How to begin trouble shooting an sql injection attack?

Tags: server

noob here...  I paid someone to find out why my joomla site was slowing down and exceeding bandwidth etc.

They told me that I was experiencing an sql injection attack through my RSS feed, they did some work on my site that I don't understand that was supposed to block or slow down the problem. I don't think its working.

Can anyone point me a tutorial or tell me what tools a noob my start with to analyze my site/server?

Answer (score 2):

Take down any scripts which may contain exploitable code to prevent further abuse immediately. A malicious user who has enumerated an SQL injection vulnerability has his foot in the door to cause some serious problems for your site and you're asking for trouble if you are working to fix the problem while the exploit remains available.

Once you have secured your site, you can audit questionable code to patch the issue - look for any `mysql_query()` or `mysqli_query()` calls which include variables which are not wrapped in `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` calls (ideally, you'll replace these calls with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) using bound parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry
try this

http://sqlzoo.net/hack/

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

hope it helps you